# how to WEB SCRAPE XML SITEMAP

Tags: xml, sitemap

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to scrape a website's sitemap and every time that there is a change to the sitemap, record/log what was changed and deliver this to an email address or telegram account.

Does anyone know if this is possible, if so where to get started?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**I am assuming you already scrape the sitemap.**

Yes, it is possible. You need to schedule the task which automatically triggers after regular intervals.

In this task, you need to read the sitemap of the website and save all the URLs in the database. You have to add the condition of either the URL is already in the database or not. If the URL is new and not available in the database then you will send that URL to email/telegram and also add that URL to the database.

Every time the scheduler tasks run it will find all the new URLs and will send you in the email and update the database.
Hope this is helpful.

If you didn't scrape the sitemap yet. You can do this by JSOUP/Scrapy.